# Android Listview include layout click list item

Tags: android, android-listview

This is a really odd problem.I have an XML layout for a row in a List view and I added another Layout using include.

Without this included layout, list item clicks work. With it the don't. It's just a layout.

Some code:

```
<!--
<include
    layout="@layout/card_loyalty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
-->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pocketImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/holder_pocket" />
```

This works well, if I remove the comment section, does not detect list item cliks

Card Loyalty XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="206dp">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cardName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/card_details_card_name"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cardNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/card_details_card_number"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCardImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/card_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. For some reason the ImageButton was creating the problem. I changed it to ImageView and now I can click list items again.